# Как получить элементы из данного JSON

Tags: java, json, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

```
response: [
    { 
        id: 1, 
        first_name: 'Павел', 
        last_name: 'Дуров', 
        sex: 2, 
        photo_id: '1_288668576', 
        can_write_private_message: 0 
    }, 
    { 
        id: 2, 
        first_name: 'Александра', 
        last_name: 'Владимирова', 
        sex: 1, 
        photo_id: '2_332227351', 
        can_write_private_message: 0 
    }, 
    { 
        id: 3, 
        first_name: 'DELETED',
        last_name: '', 
        deactivated: 'deleted', 
        sex: 0, 
        can_write_private_message: 0 
    }
]
```

Как в Java получить ID из всех элементов? Использую библиотеку *com.google.gson*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Способ для ленивых

Получили объектную модель — и вперёд.

```
JsonArray a = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonArray();
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    int id = a.get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("id").getAsInt();
}
```

## Долгий способ

Описываем классы...

```
class Human {
    string id;
    // ...
}
```

...и имеем гламурный массивчик:

```
Human[] humans = new Gson().fromJson(json, Human[].class);
```

## Правильный способ

Найдите готовую обёртку над API и не мучайтесь. Всё изобретено до вас.

Comment: Ну я не нашёл подходящий API для своих "проектов", и решил сделать свой, больше месяца ею пользовался, и вот сейчас мне попался такой массив, который я вижу в первые. Спасибо за код! c:

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Array.
с моим кодом было тоже самое

Comment: @МихаилИванов У вас вокруг `response: [ ]` случайно фигурных скобочек не было, про которые вы забыли упомянуть? Тогда надо начинать с `...getAsJsonObject().get("response")`.

Comment: не, не было, я в вопросе вставил весь json

Comment: @МихаилИванов Приведённый вами текст не является валидным JSON. Снаружи должно быть или `{ ... }`, или `[ ... ]` (плюс может быть голый примитив). `{ response: [ { id: ... } ... ] }` — правильно, `[ { id: ... } ... ]` — правильно, `response: [ { id: ... } ... ]` — неправильно. Вы определённо что-то упускаете из вида.

Comment: ой, извините, я JSON взял из документации VKApi, и только что заметил что там без {}. спасибо!